# Getting notified when any command gets executed in the Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, command

I am planning to write a logger for my WPF application which logs every command that gets executed in my application. I don't want to put the logging logic in the handlers for every command.

Is there a way for me to get notified whenever any command gets executed in my application?

Thanks
jbsp72

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to do the logging at the window level and then let the event tunnel to the control for further action?

Comment: I thought of getting all the command bindings associated with my window and hooking onto each of them. But I would not be able to hook up to dynamically created command bindings. I would have to monitor changes to the list of command bindings as well and keep registering deregistering commands.